# Cookie safety issues

Tags: c#, session, cookies

How can I remember a user that is logged in without having a security issue? Currently, I am storing the id and a guid into two different cookies and compare them when there is no session alive. If it match then I re-create the session. Btw, both id and guid are nore encrypted.

Is this method safe enough, or should I follow a rather distinct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since cookies can be easily stolen by use of XSS, does not matter if you place information in just one cookie or two, because a theft will take them all.

I have solved with a more complex procedure: I place one encrypted cookie divided in 2 parts (but 2 cookies will work as well), one fixed and the other variable each session. Both are saved also on server side to check: they are only session identifiers, no sensible information contained in the cookie, the correspondence with the user id is saved on the server.

If a fake user enters the account with a stolen cookie, the variable part (or cookie) will change, so when real user connects again he will not be able to enter and you will have the proof that an unauthorized access occurred: then you can delete the permanent session on server side (defined by the fixed part or cookie) in order to avoid any further access by the theft. The real user will re-login and create a new permanent session with a new cookie. You can also warn him that you saw a security flaw, suggesting him to reset password (operation that should never be accessible directly from cookie) or to use another browser for unsafe navigation.

If you save additional user information (user-agent, IP by location) you can check cookie validity also on them in order to avoid even the first entrance of the fake user.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) for tracking logged in users in an ASP.NET application.